# Android Kotlin Error - Property adapter has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin-android-extensions

**Technical Aspects:** Android Kotlin

I have a page with SearchView inside Toolbar i.e. on top of the page which will basically search an item from the list populated below. However when I'm trying to enter some text inside the SearchView it shows the below two error's: -

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapter
> has not been initialized
> at com.example.myfirstapp.ListPage.getAdapter(ListPage.kt:22)
> at com.example.myfirstapp.ListPage$onCreateOptionsMenu$1.onQueryTextChange(ListPage.kt:140)

**ListView.xml: -**

```
                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                                <LinearLayout
                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                tools:context=".ListPage">

                                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/listV"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                                </ListView>
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/emptyView"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:text="No Results"
                                    android:textSize="20sp"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />

                            </LinearLayout>
```

**ListPage.kt: -**

```
            package com.example.myfirstapp
            import android.app.Activity
            import android.content.Intent
            import android.os.Bundle
            import android.view.Menu
            import android.view.MenuItem
            import android.view.View
            import android.view.ViewGroup
            import android.widget.*
            import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
            import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
            import com.example.myfirstapp.R
            import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
            import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_vw.*
            import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_list.view.*
            import java.security.PrivateKey

            class ListPage : AppCompatActivity() {
                private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
                //lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapter
                lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
                private lateinit var listView: ListView
                private lateinit var emptyView: TextView

                override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                    setContentView(R.layout.list_vw)

                    /*var actionBar = getSupportActionBar()

                    if (actionBar != null) {

                        // Customize the back button
                        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.mybutton);

                        // showing the back button in action bar
                        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    }*/

                    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
                   // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    emptyView = findViewById(R.id.emptyView)
                    //find listview
                    var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listV)

                    //CustomAdapter
                    var customAdapter = CustomAdapter(this)
                    listView.adapter = customAdapter

                        listView.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked: " + customAdapter.names[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        var intent = Intent(applicationContext,NextPage::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    listView.emptyView = emptyView
                }

                class CustomAdapter(private val context:Activity):BaseAdapter() {
                    var names = arrayOf("Apple","Strawberry","Bannana","Peach","Cocout")
                    var desc = arrayOf("Red and round","Red","Yellow","Pink","Green")
                    var image= intArrayOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

                    override fun getCount(): Int {
                        return image.size
                    }

                    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
                        return image[position]
                    }

                    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
                        return image[position].toLong()
                    }

                    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

                        var inflater= context.layoutInflater
                        var view1= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list,null)

                        //find view
                        var fName= view1.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fName)
                        var fDesc= view1.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fDescp)
                        var fImage= view1.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fImage)

                        fName.setText(names[position])
                        fDesc.setText(desc[position])
                        fImage.setImageResource(image[position])
                        return view1
                    }
                }

                override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        android.R.id.home -> {
                            finish()
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
                }

            /*    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                    val inflater= menuInflater
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu)
                    return true
                }
                override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    return when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.edit -> {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Edit Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            return true
                        }
                        R.id.share -> {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Share Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            return true
                        }
                        R.id.delete -> {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Deleted Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            return true
                        }

                        else ->
                            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
                    }
                }*/

                override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menus, menu)
                    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.appSearchBar)
                    val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
                    searchView.queryHint = "Search"
                    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                            return false
                        }
                        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                            //listView.adapter = customAdapter
                            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
                }

            }
```

Comment: You have not initialized lateinit variable  `adapter` in your code.

Comment: Thanks Nitish, actually i have already declared lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>, can you please help on what changes do i need to make? is it something like replacing <*> with String/Int type?

Comment: That's declaration , you need to initialize it also. I don't see any use of `adpater` variable in your code, I believe it should be `customAdapter` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` , as that's the adapter in which set your list and also in list view